# Mvvm model validation with INotifyDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifydataerrorinfo

my model implements the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface to validate it's properties, and it works fine, but the probleme is, the property HasErrors is by default false, so when i run my app at the first time and click save (form is empty) the view raise no errors, and the data is saved.

here is a snipet of my viewmodel

```
public LoggingViewModel()
{
    _loggingCommand = new RelayCommand(checkCredentials, canExecuteLogginForm);
    _logingModel = new LoggingModel();

    // I raise this event in the 'OnErrorsChanged' method in the model,
    // so my ViewModel can subscribe and check the 'HasErrors' property.
    _logingModel.FormIsValid += (o, e) => _loggingCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}

private bool canExecuteLogginForm()
{
    return !_logingModel.HasErrors;
}
```

how do you handle this situation in your app?

for more info i created this [github](https://github.com/veteran1/MvvmValidation) repos.

Comment: Can you update your code so by default HasErrors is True? That or force validation in your LogginModel constructor?

Comment: HasErrors is a member of INotifyDataErrorInfo interface, it should return false when there is no error in the form. how can I force the validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `LogginModel` is actually in an invalid state originally you should call the `ValidateForm()` method in its constructor to actually set it into this state and populate the _`errors` dictionary in order for the `HasErrors` property to return `true` as it should:

```
public class LoggingModel : PocoBase
{
    public LoggingModel()
    {
        ValidateForm();
    }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [MaxLength(32), MinLength(4)]
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(); }
        set { SetValue(value); }
    }

    [Required]
    public string Password
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(); }
        set { SetValue(value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel logic is correct.
Problem is in your validation logic inside the model which is returning HasErrors = False when HasErrors = true.

Take a look at how you are setting/returning/evaluating HasErrors.
Are you validating the Model on property get?

```
    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get
        {
            bool hasErrors = false; // Default true here?

            // Validation logic ...

            return hasErrors;
        }
    }
```

Are you storing the HasError value in a property and setting it somewhere else?

```
    public LoggingModel()
    {
        HasErrors = true; // Default true here?
    }

    public bool HasErrors { get; set; } // Gets set via validation logic
```

Just some ideas, like I said if you can show the structure on how you handle INotifyDataErrorInfo validation I can give a better answer.